# ASIHTTPRequest cache

Tags: ios, http, ios4, asihttprequest

I want to cache my requests. If I set this line in app delegate will all my requests cached?

```
[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
```

I have one more question. Can I have more than one cookie? Thanks :)

Comment: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use , scroll down to "Using a download cache" (use control-f to find and paste the title..). It will start using shared caching, not suer what it means but it should start caching.